# Another UNKNOWN provider Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

OK so I am new to angular and I have been searching for answers all over the web to this problem. I am having an unknown provider error and I am not able to find the right answer I have tried multiple replies from here on stack overflow and alot of other places but it has not helped me find the right answer for it yet.

I have the Module.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','app.student']).config(['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($httpProvider,$routeProvider) {
//Various code
}]);
```

Here is my Controller

```
angular.module('app.student', []).controller('StudentCtrl', ['StudentService', '$scope', '$http', function (StudentService, $scope, $http) {
 //Code 
 }]);
```

And now My service

```
angular.module('app.student', []).service('StudentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
// Some More Code
}]);
```

I am still new to this language, I have again tried multiple answers on Stackoverflow and None of the answers are working for me. So I just decided to ask for some help. Thanks

P.S. if you need more of my code just let me know.

Comment: Remove the brackets [] from the other two module calls. You only use the brackets in the module method when you first define it. Otherwise, you leave it off and just use the name to reference a created module.

That being said, you've created three different modules (because of the brackets): 'app' and 2 occurrences of 'app.student'. I don't know if you'd intended those all to be the same module or not...

Comment: "I have again tried multiple answers on Stackoverflow and None of the answers are working for me"  In the future tell us what you tried so we don't give you solutions you've already attempted.  This helps us not waste our time - or yours.

Comment: Amy, Sorry I did not think about that but I will keep it in mind next time I have a question. Thanks alot for all of the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have app.student as a dependency,

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).config(['$httpProvider', '$routeProvider', function ($httpProvider,$routeProvider) {
//Various code
}]);
```

your controller code should be,

```
angular.module('app').controller('StudentCtrl', ['StudentService', '$scope', '$http', function (StudentService, $scope, $http) {
 //Code 
 }]);
```

and service should be,

```
angular.module('app').service('StudentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
// Some More Code
}]);
```

Comment: Maybe the OP wants a separate module though?

Comment: Hey Sajeetharan, your answered helped me realize my mistake thanks alot! That is exactly the way I wanted it to work. This is a pretty nifty site!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating the `app.student` module twice.

First you create your module (and then you also create a controller):

```
angular.module('app.student', []).controller('StudentCtrl', ['StudentService', '$scope', '$http', function (StudentService, $scope, $http) {
     //Code 
 }]);
```

Then once it's created, just retrieve it. Don't pass in an array of dependencies, or you will create it again:

```
angular.module('app.student').service('StudentService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    // Some More Code
}]);
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I speculate it was downvoted because your answer is incomplete.  There shouldn't be a dependency on 'app.student', apparently.

Comment: @Amy Why should there not be a dependency on a separate module, if that's how the OP wants to structure their app? The line `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','app.student'])` makes me think the separate module is intentional.

Comment: I have no idea, I'm just stating what the other answer suggests as the issue.